# No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of ‘==’

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell and I'm trying to solve this haskell problem http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10#Problem_7 . To verify the result I created some tests using `Test.QuickCheck` module.

```
    import Test.QuickCheck
    import Test.QuickCheck.All

    {- ------------- -}
    {- SOLUTION      -}
    {- ------------- -}

    data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]

    flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
    flatten (Elem x) = [x]
    flatten (List x) = concatMap flatten x

    {- ------------- -}
    {- TEST CASE     -}
    {- ------------- -}

    main = do
        quickCheck (flatten (Elem 5) == [5])
        quickCheck (flatten (List [Elem 1, List [Elem 2, List [Elem 3, Elem 4], Elem 5]]) == [1,2,3,4,5])
        quickCheck (flatten (List []) == [])
```

The `flatten` implementation is correct but, when I try to run this code I have an error with the `quickCheck` functions.

```
    Problem7.hs:43:39:
        No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of ‘==’
        The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
        Note: there are several potential instances:
          instance Eq a => Eq (GHC.Real.Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
          instance Eq () -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
          instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a, b) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
          ...plus 114 others
        In the first argument of ‘quickCheck’, namely
          ‘(flatten (List []) == [])’
        In a stmt of a 'do' block: quickCheck (flatten (List []) == [])
        In the expression:
          do { quickCheck (flatten (Elem 5) == [5]);
               quickCheck (flatten (List [Elem 1, List [...]]) == [1, 2, ....]);
               quickCheck (flatten (List []) == []) }
```

I know that I need to have an instance of `Eq` to perform the comparisons with (==) function, but I don't know how to implement it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the statement

```
quickCheck (flatten (List []) == [])
```

and it's because you have `List []`, which has type `NestedList a`, but you want it to be `Eq a => NestedList a`.  Even though there are no values in it, when you use the `==` operator it enforces that the type belong to the `Eq` typeclass.  There are two simple fixes around this:

Instead of comparing a list against the empty list, use `null`, which has the implementation

```
null :: [a] -> Bool
null [] = True
null _ = False
```

This is what I (and the `hlint` tool) would suggest doing.  Alternatively, you can provide it with an explicit type signature:

```
quickCheck (flatten (List [] :: NestedList ()) == [])
```

Here I've used `()` as the type parameter to `NestedList`, since its implementation is equivalent to

```
data () = ()

instance Eq () where
    () == () = True
```

So you can't really go wrong with it.

Comment: @Diullei Glad I could help!  FYI, depending on the editor you're using there might be an `hlint` plugin (I know there is for emacs, possibly for vim, and I use the one for Sublime Text) which is really useful for spotting these kinds of errors.  If you don't have a plugin for your editor, you can just install `hlint` and use it from the command line to give you suggestions like this.  I've been saved many times by that tool from having this exact error because I always forget that there's a difference between `null someList` and `someList == []`.

Comment: I started to learn Haskell recently and I'm looking for a good editor or IDE to use. At this moment I'm using sublime without plugin and I'm using `runhaskell` command line to test. I'll try use some plugin with sublime following your experience ;). Many thanks!

Comment: @Diullei specifically you'll want SublimeHaskell and SublimeLinter+SublimeLinter-hlint, and you'll have to read the instructions on how to get them set 6 because there's several extra steps to get them working. They aren't the easiest to get set up, but once you have them it has a lot of great and useful features.