# Why must element type of list be Eq when checking for empty list

Tags: haskell

The following `reverse'` function has type `Eq t => [t] -> [t]`:

```
reverse' list | list == [] = []
              | otherwise  = (reverse' listTail) ++ [listHead]
                where (listHead : listTail) = list
```

Why must the elements of the list be members of the typeclass `Eq`? I'm not comparing the elements for equality but the *list* they are contained in.

In my intuition, the list of `t` must be equatable, but `t` itself doesn't.

Comment: Aside from the type issue, can you see why your function is O(n^2)? Can you figure out how to make it O(n)?

Comment: This question is a near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664501/no-instance-for-eq-a0-arising-from-a-use-of, but this one is much more to-the-point and has better answers.

Comment: By the way, you coding style is dangerously using partial operations: whenever `list` is empty, the variables `listHead` and `listTail` will be bound to an erroneous value (AKA bottom). In that case, any attempt to use those variables will crash the whole program. The programmer must carefully guard all such uses with a non-null test. By comparison, using proper, exhaustive pattern matching as suggested below in the answers fixes the partiality problem _and_ does not even require the `Eq` constraint. This is why, arguably, pattern matching should always be preferred to using guards.

Comment: @dfeuer: Thanks for the hint! Yes, `reverse' listTail` and `++` are *both* O(n) which makes this function O(n^2). I presume `foldl` would be useful to make the function less complex.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun, you certainly could use `foldl` for this purpose (although there's a subtle reason to be careful about that because it can potentially interact very badly with certain GHC optimizations in some cases). But you can (and should!) start by doing it by hand using a helper function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because we can only compare lists in general for equality if we can compare their elements for equality. That is, in the general case there's no real way to explain `[a, b, c] == [d, e, f]` unless we can explain `a == d`.

This is reflected in the type of `(==)` on lists which after all works for both your case and the more generalized one:

```
 (==) :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

However you don't want to compare a list of equality with another list really, you just want to check whether a list is empty and so

```
 null :: [a] -> Bool
```

is a far better choice for you. And it doesn't have that equality constraint because it just uses pattern matching on the structure of the list, something that never requires a type class constraint.

```
  null :: [a] -> Bool
  null [] = True
  null (_ : _) = False
```

Even better in your case would be to just do the pattern matching yourself, after all, you're already right by a pattern!

```
reverse' [] = []
reverse' (listHead : listTail) = (reverse' listTail) ++ [listHead]
```

This is much closer to idiomatic Haskell because verifying that it doesn't crash can be done trivially by the compiler, we've exhaustively covered all cases in a way that it can check. In your version, to verify that the code would work we had to trace the two paths through the code and ensure an empty list would never end up in the branch where we had done that pattern match. This is only a small problem right now, but it will creep up in difficulty very quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Because `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` only works for instances of `Eq`, and `[]` is only an instance of `Eq` if its elements are an instance of `Eq`:

```
instance (Eq a) => Eq [a] where
    ...
```

Instead, use `null :: [a] -> Bool` or pattern matching to check whether a list is empty:

```
reverse' [] = []
reverse' xs = ...
```

Comment: Or pattern matching.